# how to filter and transform a List<Map<String,object>> in to new List<Map<String,object>> with different key value

Tags: java-8, sonarqube

I am getting sonar response from sonar search api in the form of List<Map<String,Object>> -

```
[   
        {
            "key": "KY1",
            "name": "key1",
            "qualifier": "KYK",
            "visibility": "public",
            "lastAnalysisDate": "2022-09-10T08:01:13+0000",
            "revision": "bidvbu5u59"
        },
        {
            "key": "KY2",
            "name": "key2",
            "qualifier": "KYK",
            "visibility": "public",
            "lastAnalysisDate": "2023-02-26T09:53:08+0000",
            "revision": "bibnodsfnfbidvbu5u59"
        },
        {
            "key": "KY3",
            "name": "key3",
            "qualifier": "KYK",
            "visibility": "public",
            "lastAnalysisDate": "2023-02-07T14:07:31+0000",
            "revision": "bibnodsfnfbidvbu5u59"
        }
    ]
```

Now, I have a list that have name of the key i.e. key, name that needs to be picked up from the above response and again transform it in to below form

```
[   
        {
            "key": "KY1",
            "value": "key1"
        },
        {
            "key": "KY2",
            "value": "key2"
        },
        {
            "key": "KY3",
            "value": "key3"
        }
    ]
```

The List of keys as mentioned above is fetched from the database. The list could grow or shrink as per the DB entry.
The List is in the form -

```
List<String> keys = new ArrayList<>();
            keys.add("key");
            keys.add("name");
```

Comment: Suppose the keys list is having,`key,name,qualifier` , are you expecting the output be `[[{key=key, value=KY1}, {key=name, value=key1}, {key=qualifier, value=KYK}], [{key=key, value=KY2}, {key=name, value=key2}, {key=qualifier, value=KYK}], [{key=key, value=KY3}, {key=name, value=key3}, {key=qualifier, value=KYK}]]` ? based on your list of Map provided in the question?

Comment: @Coder I am expecting value - [   
        {
            "key": "KY1",
            "value": "key1",
    "qualifier": "KYK"
        },
        {
            "key": "KY2",
            "value": "key2",
    "qualifier": "KYK"
        },
        {
            "key": "KY3",
            "value": "key3",
    "qualifier":  "KYK"
        }
    ]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use streams to get desired output. Use the stream in the API response first, and within the map, use the stream for your list of keys to be extracted and return as a map.

It will return a stream of maps which can be merged together in the last part (https://www.baeldung.com/java-merge-maps#of)

```
// The API Response data
List<Map<String, Object>> list = new ArrayList<>();
```

### Java 17

If you want to keep the order, you need to use LinkedHashMap normally. Given in Java 8 section below.

```
List<Map<String, Object>> output = list.stream().map(mapObj -> {
    return keys.stream().map(key -> {       
        String keyStr = switch (key) {
        case "key" -> "key"; // This is not necessary as default case will handle it. 
        case "name" -> "value";
        default -> key;
        };
        return Map.of(keyStr, mapObj.get(key));
    }).flatMap(map -> map.entrySet().stream())
            .collect(Collectors.toMap(Map.Entry::getKey, Map.Entry::getValue, (v1, v2) -> v1));
}).toList();
```

### Java 8

```
List<LinkedHashMap<String, Object>> output = list.stream().map(mapObj -> {
            return keys.stream().map(key -> {
                String keyStr = key;
                if ("key".equals(keyStr)) {
                    keyStr = "key";
                }
                if ("name".equals(key)) {
                    keyStr = "value";
                }

                Map<String, Object> out = new LinkedHashMap<>();
                out.put(keyStr, mapObj.get(key));
                return out;
            }).flatMap(map -> map.entrySet().stream()).collect(
                    Collectors.toMap(Map.Entry::getKey, Map.Entry::getValue, (v1, v2) -> v1, LinkedHashMap::new));
        }).collect(Collectors.toList());
```